# Blanks when trying to filter on previous business date using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter on the prior business date using vba. Getting blanks.

I tried to enter the actual date 01/30/19 in the Criterial: and it works, but when I run my code nothing shows up.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim xDay As String
Dim xDate As Date
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

 Set sht = wb.Sheets("Open PO Raw Data")

If xDay = "Monday" Then
    xDate = Date - 3
Else
    xDate = Date - 1
End If

'
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  sht.Range("A1:G" & LastRow).AutoFilter field:=7, _
  Criteria1:="xdate"
```

I would like the column G to show all dates for 01/30/19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes `"` around `xdate` in `Criteria1:="xdate"` mean your filter criterion is the *text* "xdate", not the *value* of the variable `xDate`. Remove the quotes.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments, it sounded like you were dealing with text, not actual dates. In that case, you could use `Criteria1:=Format(xDate, "mm/dd/yy")`.

Comment: I still get blanks when I removed the quotes.

Comment: Are your dates possibly *text-that-look-like-dates"?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the date. In the spreadsheet the date is mm/dd/yy and the xDate is m/dd/yyyy.  I tried to change the format in the spreadsheet to that and I would still get blanks.

Comment: Try `Criteria1:=Format(xDate, "mm/dd/yy")`.